# ¿Cómo pasar codigo de JavaScript a Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

soy nuevo en la rama de la programación
Estoy trabajando con Angular pero se me a dificultado pasar codigo de JavaScript a Typescrip.

Este es el codigo que intento pasar a Typescript

```
function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 14,
      center: {lat: 19.12999, lng: -99.6900}
    });
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

    document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function() {
      geocodeLatLng(geocoder, map, infowindow);
    });
  }

  function geocodeLatLng(geocoder, map, infowindow) {
    var input = document.getElementById('latlng').value;
    var latlngStr = input.split(',', 2);   
    var latlng = {lat: parseFloat(latlngStr[0]), lng: parseFloat(latlngStr[1])};
    geocoder.geocode({'location': latlng}, function(results, status) {
      if (status === 'OK') {
        if (results[0]) {
          map.setZoom(14);
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map
          });
          infowindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        } else {
          window.alert('No results found');
        }
      } else {
        window.alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
      }
    });
  }
```

Alguna sugerencia me seria de gran ayuda

Comment: te ha dado algun problema? en realidad Typescript cambia a JS al final asi que no tiene mucho caso pasarlo a TS si va a regresar a JS

Answer (score 1):

Para migrar el código de javascript a Typescript hay que evitar var  (desde ES2015 javascript también) y usar const (en caso que el valor del objeto sea constante) o let (en caso que varíe (se modifique) el valor del objeto).

Además se ha de verificar que el elemento obtenido a través de "document.getElementById" no es nulo.

El resultado de la migración sería algo así:

```
function initMap() {
  // replace var with const or let
  // const if is contant/ let if can change
  const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 14,
    center: { lat: 19.12999, lng: -99.6900 }
  });
  const geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
  const infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

  // verify document.getElementId is defined
  const elementSubmit = document.getElementById('submit');
  if (elementSubmit) {
    elementSubmit.addEventListener('click', () => {
      geocodeLatLng(geocoder, map, infowindow);
    });
  }
}

function geocodeLatLng(geocoder, map, infowindow) {
  const elementLatLng = document.getElementById('latlng');
  // verify if element is null or not is an htmlinputelement return
  if (!elementLatLng || !(elementLatLng instanceof HTMLInputElement)) return;

  // value not exist on HTML Element
  const input = (<HTMLInputElement>elementLatLng).innerText;
  const latlngStr = input.split(',', 2);
  const latlng = { lat: parseFloat(latlngStr[0]), lng: parseFloat(latlngStr[1]) };
  geocoder.geocode({ 'location': latlng }, (results, status) => {
    if (status === 'OK') {
      if (results[0]) {
        map.setZoom(14);
        const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: latlng,
          map: map
        });
        infowindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      } else {
        window.alert('No results found');
      }
    } else {
      window.alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
    }
  });
}
```

document.getElementById retorna un objeto HTMLElement el cual no contiene la propiedad value, pudiendo castear este objeto por HTMLInputElement (si el elemento es un input) y obtener el valor.

Para usar la librería de google maps has de instalarte el paquete https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/googlemaps

Un Saludo.

Comment: PERO esto sigue siendo sintáxis de JavaScript y la pregunta pide pasarlo a TS

Comment: Acabo de hacerlo en Typescript simplemente las diferencias son semanticas, luego ya depende de si quiere integrarlo en una clase, efectuar las funciones globales o exportarlas directamente. Faltando esa información lo único que se puede efectuar es migrar la parte que typescript rechaza para transpilarlo.